# Errors when trying to process CiviCRM contribution with BackdropCMS

Tags: civicontribute, stripe, backdrop

Using CiviCRM with Backdrop CMS.
The site is running 5.59.3.

When we try to process a transaction we were getting this error: `Session invalid. Please reload and try again`

See: https://forum.backdropcms.org/forum/backdropcivicrm-error-session-invalid-please-reload-and-try-again

After playing around with this and updating CiviCRM, we are now getting this error when processing a transaction:

`Sorry an error occurred and your request was not completed. (Error ID: cumu-Jnkb-MjLE)`

The Backdrop LOG gives us this:

```
AJAX Error ({error_id}): failed with exception Array ( [error_id] => cumu-Jnkb-MjLE [exception] => CRM_Core_Exception: "Bad Request" 
#0 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php(72): Civi\Api4\Action\StripePaymentintent\ProcessPublic->_run() 
#1 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(158): Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider->invoke() 
#2 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(250): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest() 
#3 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(85): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute() 
#4 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/CRM/Api4/Page/AJAX.php(138): civicrm_api4() 
#5 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/CRM/Api4/Page/AJAX.php(79): CRM_Api4_Page_AJAX->execute() 
#6 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(319): CRM_Api4_Page_AJAX->run() 
#7 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem() 
#8 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke() 
#9 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/modules/civicrm/backdrop/civicrm.module(551): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke() 
#10 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/core/includes/menu.inc(584): civicrm_invoke() 
#11 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/core/modules/layout/layout.module(639): menu_default_route_handler() 
#12 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/core/includes/menu.inc(531): layout_route_handler() 
#13 /var/www/---/prod/src/web/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() #14 {main} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Session issues can be related to mixed http/https [www.example.com/example.com](http://www.example.com/example.com).  Check your browser console network tab and ensure they are all consistent.